# Bootstrap Image templates & share buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was looking for this image template (1*), but didn't find anything. Is there a class for this in Bootstrap?

Also, what is the best way to create the share buttons (2*).
[image]

Comment: For Point#1 => https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=500%C3%97330&w=500&h=330

Comment: For Point#2 => Use, https://www.addthis.com/get/share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point 1: If your using bootstrap 4: [Bootstap 4 Component: Cards](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#images)

Point 2: I would recommend coding them in from the respective servicd yourself (facebook, twitter etc have widgets to do this kind of thing) or possibly use a service like: [Add This](https://www.addthis.com/get/share)

Comment: I am not using bootstrap 4 for the first part, so any other way? I think this is from an old article, like 2014 or something.

Answer (score 0):

**Point # 1** Below script will work for Bootstrap v3.
https://jsfiddle.net/wob917Lq

**Html & CSS**
`

```
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=500%C3%97330&w=500&h=330" alt="">
          <div class="caption">
            <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=500%C3%97330&w=500&h=330" alt="">
          <div class="caption">
            <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=500%C3%97330&w=500&h=330" alt="">
          <div class="caption">
            <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=500%C3%97330&w=500&h=330" alt="">
          <div class="caption">
            <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div><!-- End row -->

</div><!-- End container -->` `<style type="text/css">
.thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
 }
.thumbnail img {
    width: 100%;
 }
.caption{
  background: black;
  color: white ! important;
  text-align: center;
 }</style>`
```

**Point # 2** Please check this link https://www.sharethis.com